# How to convert a plain text(with underscore) to hyperlink by regex pattern in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to convert a plain text to hyperlink in C#. I am using regex pattern to replace for the same. But I am facing an issue that if any underscore is present in the text, it was failed to convert it to hyperlink.

I have attached the code snippet

```
**string regex = @"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])";
        Regex r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return r.Replace(s, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"&#95;blank\">$1</a>").Replace("href=\"www", "href=\"http://www");**
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

I also attached the Screenshot of the issue.[image]

Comment: try this expression `((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9._\-]+\.[a-z0-9_\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])`

Comment: So add the underscore to that arbitrary list of allowed characters that you have in the square brackets? It is very broken though because in square brackets each character is separate from the rest, so your `&#95;` and `##` do not do what you think they do.